# Block internet access to all programs except for whitelisted ones

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create firewall “profiles” for Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/242515/create-firewall-profiles-for-windows-7)

Sometimes my home internet connection drops, and I have to switch to a tethered mobile one which has a data limit. This means I have to close pretty much all applications except a fresh internet browser to make sure there are no bandwidth-wasting applications running.

I would like to know if there is a program that lets me block all programs' internet access by default, and use a whitelist to let applications through this block. On/Off switch would be nice, but closing the program and then re-opening it when I need it again is fine too.

Comment: windows 7? vista? xp?

Comment: @Logman Windows 7, sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: On XP it's possible with [Sygate](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10494/903) (in fact that's how it works by default, i.e. with white listing)

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the firewall. Software-based or hardware-based.

Here is a good tutorial on how to make rules in [windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=112564)

There are some 3rd party firewalls applications that can be easier to use like [Comodo](http://personalfirewall.comodo.com/) or [ZoneAlarm](http://www.zonealarm.com/security/en-us/zonealarm-pc-security-free-firewall.htm) (free versions), and then some not so free. But we need to know what OS you are running...

Comment: I use windows 7. Firewalls usually work with blacklists (allow by default, block individually). I want to work  the other way around; with a whitelist. And I need to be able to switch that around conveniently.

Comment: I am pretty sure Comodo can block all outgoing with whitelist. I will verify...

Comment: I just tried ZoneAlarm, I can tell for sure that one does not support whitelisting. Hopefully you have better luck with Comodo ;)

Comment: well, with Comodo you can export / import config profiles... but you would have to manually deny or except everything using paranoid mode. But once you get it set you could switch between the settings. Not simple...

Comment: Too much of a hassle really.. if anybody has a good solution for this I am all ears, but +1 for your efforts, much appreciated.