# Windows 8: Block Internet except for all but two programs

Tags: windows-8, internet-connection, windows-firewall

*Question marked as duplicate, as is nearly every other question about blacklisting and whitelisting. Some of these questions are different because:
1) XP has a different firewall than Vista/Win7/Win8
2) Some questions are about blacklisting, others whitelisting.
3) Some whitelisting questions are by domain names, others by application.
4) Some questions are focusing on easily switching profiles, while others are seeking permanence.
The main answer that has been provided from the linked duplicates is how to configure the Windows firewall. This does not completely help, and even where it does, is not very easy.
My answer was to use tinywall, which seems to be working. Might i suggest that these questions are not so easily marked as duplicates, because the nuances of each can make a huge difference in whether previous answers are applicable.*

A friend has a laptop running Windows 8.1 which is using an Internet connect from T-Mobile's Rocket (USB/4G) which comes with 200 MB/month for life. The purpose of the Internet connection is to use Fast Forward for his son, which should use about 50MB/month for our usage of it. So, the 200MB should be enough, possibly for virus definitions as well. His house has no other Internet connection, and no wireless networks are strong enough to be used. Periodically, if required, i can bring his laptop to my apartment and get him all pending updates (as i am doing right now).

A such, i want to block all traffic except for Fast Forward and Windows Defender definition updates. Will the Windows Firewall do that? If so, how?

--

For the first week or two, he also wants to get healthcare under the new law. So, browsing needs to be available at first. Extra Internet bandwidth will be purchased as required for this endeavor, but i'd like to help him keep that to a minimum for him as well.

How would we best go about this?

Comment: Try not allowing any internet browser.  If say IE is unable to connect then you have successfully block casual internet browsing.  Honestly you are going to have create custom rules for every single application that is installed, an go against the very nature of today's environment, in order to achieve it.  Here is a question on the subject http://superuser.com/questions/450198/temporary-block-all-incoming-and-outgoing-except-chrome-in-windows-firewall?rq=1

Comment: The answer, for me, was Tinywall. It's free and it allows simple whitelisting with tools to find what is being used.