# How do I configure the Windows firewall to block communication with all except one IP address?

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-firewall

so I am the admin of a club laptop, which runs on windows 10, and is connected to the internet via an usb stick with a sim card, which unfortunately has limited internet, so to prevent people from watching for example youtube videos, i want to block all websites,but one, which is the club site. 
Is there any way of doing this with the windows firewall?
Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest the following approach:

1. Save the current firewall rules
2. Set the default outbound firewall policy to block all
3. Delete all outbound firewall rules
4. Add a single rule to allow your website

Below are the directions in detail.

## **Save the current firewall rules**

- Start *Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security*
- Right-click the upper item - *Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security*
- Select *Export Policy...*
- Follow the prompts to save.

[image]

## **Set the default outbound firewall policy to block all**

- Right-click again the upper item - *Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security*
- Select *Properties*
- Switch *Outbound connections* from "Allow (default)" to "Block"
  [image]

## **Delete all outbound firewall rules**

- Click on *Outbound Rules*
- Click on the middle pane on some item to set the focus
- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the rules
- Right-click any selected rule and choose *Delete*

[image]

## **Add a single rule to allow your website**

- Still in *Outbound Rules*, click in the Actions pane on *New Rule"
- Select *Custom* and *Next*
- Leave selected *All programs* and click *Next*
- Leave *Protocol Type* as *Any* and click *Next*
- In *Scope*, under *Which remote IP addresses does this rule apply to?*,
  select *These IP addresses:*
- Click *Add...* and enter the IP address of your website and click *OK*
- Click *Next*
- Select *Allow the connection* and click *Next*
- Leave all profiles checked and click *Next*
- Give a name to your rule and click *Finish*

## **Undoing this configuration**

To return to normal unblocked rules :

- Start *Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security*
- Right-click the upper item - *Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security*
- Select *Import Policy...* and point to the save file created in the first step.

You could also save the blocked state, so it may quickly be reset again
by using the Import Policy command as above.

---

In answer to the query about making it work for
[wikipedia.org](https://www.wikipedia.org/),
I believe the problem has arrived in the above step of
"Add a single rule to allow your website", which was badly written
(corrected now).

This step needs to be filled as follows, where the IP range is
`91.198.174.192/27` (found in
[this article](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikipedia_Zero/IP_Addresses)):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough instructions. In the Properties dialog it has three tabs, Domain, Public and Private. Which one do I apply these steps to? Do I need to modify the inbound rules?

Comment: In your image you have private tab selected. In my setup it says "Public profile is active". I applied these instructions to all "zones" and added an exception for the IP and it is not connecting.

Comment: If your website is using other websites, for example for JavaScript, they also need to be authorized.

Comment: If this configuration is too restrictive, you might replace it by the normal state, just adding the block of a few popular websites like google etc.

Comment: Do I apply the instructions to all three profiles (domain, public and private)? It says `"Public is Active"`. By replacing with normal state and adding a block the question is not answered as requested. And in my tests no requests are connecting.

Comment: What is your website?

Comment: The library wants Wikipedia.org only (no Windows updates, etc). If we can get that connecting through the browser I'll mark the answer solved.

Comment: I'll check it .

Comment: My step "Add a single rule to allow your website" was badly written and misleading. I have added an image for this step at the end of my answer, tested on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: On the steps above is the section, '"Switch Outbound connections from "Allow (default)" to "Block"'. There are four tabs that this could refer to. In your image you have the `Private` tab selected. Do these rules need to apply to all 4 profiles? It says in various places the Public profile is active and that has outbound set to allowed.

Comment: That depends on the type of your network. Normally for your network inside your building and connected to your router you would mark it as private, while if you take the computer to an Internet cafe or connect to some outside public network you would mark this network as public for better protection. I used Private because I didn't think that Public could possibly be involved. You may do the same with Public if you think that some visitor could bypass your setting by connecting from your computer to an outside network with WiFi.

Comment: The type of your network is set by yourself on first connection, that is when Windows asks you the question for the type of the network. You can verify the type of your network in *Control Panel > Network Connections*.

Comment: It still doesn't connect and the IP for Wikipedia.org is 208.80.154.224.

Comment: It's possible that you are getting a different IP in your part of the world. In [my above link](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikipedia_Zero/IP_Addresses) there is a list of 5 IPv4 addresses where one equals yours. For good measures you might add all of them to the rule : `91.198.174.192/27`, `103.102.166.224/27`, `198.35.26.96/27`, `208.80.153.224/27`, `208.80.154.224/27`.

Comment: Your question is answered, all that's left are small technical problems. Your action is required for awarding the bounty.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't connect @harrymc. I've looked at related questions and answers and they state that you need a minimum of core networking. It's not the IP addresses. I show no activity at all. How are you ensuring it works? I'll go through the steps again one more time on my end.

Comment: Which is your Windows version? What does "minimum of core networking" mean? My tests were done on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: Win 10. Here's one mention of Core networking, https://superuser.com/questions/450198/temporary-block-all-incoming-and-outgoing-except-chrome-in-windows-firewall?rq=1.

Comment: You might try the command given in that answer. In my case it wasn't necessary, but may be in yours.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Also, going through these steps a few times could you disable all rules instead of removing them?

Comment: Yes, disabling would also work. I remark that visitors should not be logged-on with administrator permissions.